# How to represent UML Relations with Backbone-Relational?

Tags: backbone.js, backbone-relational

I have Class Diagram looking like this :

```
ModelA 1------* ModelB 1------* ModelC 1------* ModelD
```

**Edit :**

The Data looks like that

**Data :**

```
{   "Titel" : "ModelA",
    "ModelA" : [
        {
          "Titel" : "ModelB1",
          "ModelB1" : [
                              {
              "Titel" : "ModelC1",
                              "ModelC1":[
                                { "Titel" : "ModelD1"   },
                                { "Titel" : "ModelD2"   },
                                { "Titel" : "ModelD3"   }
                              },
                              {
              "Titel" : "ModelC2",
                              "ModelC2":[
                                { "Titel" : "ModelD21"   },
                                { "Titel" : "ModelD22"   },
                                { "Titel" : "ModelD23"   }
                              },
                              ]
                 },
                 {
          "Titel" : "ModelB2",
          "ModelB2" : [
                              {
              "Titel" : "ModelC1",
                              "ModelC1":[
                                { "Titel" : "ModelD1"   },
                                { "Titel" : "ModelD2"   },
                                { "Titel" : "ModelD3"   }
                              },
                              {
              "Titel" : "ModelC2",
                              "ModelC2":[
                                { "Titel" : "ModelD21"   },
                                { "Titel" : "ModelD22"   },
                                { "Titel" : "ModelD23"   }
                              },
                              ]
                 }]
 }
```

I create those RelationalModel :

**ModelA :**

```
ModelA = Backbone.RelationalModel.extend({

  relations:[{
    type: Backbone.HasMany,
    key: 'modelb',
    relatedModel: 'ModelB',
    collectionType: 'ModelBCollection',
    reverseRelation:{
      key: 'belong To',
      includeInJSON: 'id'
    }
  }] });
```

**ModelB :**

```
ModelB = Backbone.RelationalModel.extend({

  relations:[{
    type: Backbone.HasMany,
    key: 'modelc',
    relatedModel: 'ModelC',
    collectionType: 'ModelCCollection',
    reverseRelation:{
      key: 'belong To',
      includeInJSON: 'id'
    }
  }] });
```

**ModelC :**

```
ModelC = Backbone.RelationalModel.extend({

  relations:[{
    type: Backbone.HasMany,
    key: 'modeld',
    relatedModel: 'ModelD',
    collectionType: 'ModelDCollection',
    reverseRelation:{
      key: 'belong To',
      includeInJSON: 'id'
    }
  }] });
```

**ModelD :**

```
ModelD = Backbone.Model.extend({ });
```

**Collections :**

```
 ModelACollection = Backbone.Collection.extend({ model: ModelA });
 ModelBCollection = Backbone.Collection.extend({ model: ModelB });
 ModelCCollection = Backbone.Collection.extend({ model: ModelC });
 ModelDCollection = Backbone.Collection.extend({ model: ModelD });
```

and i do this in the Router :

**Router :**

```
var obja = new ModelACollection(data);
var objb = new ModelBCollection(data.objb);
var objc = new ModelCCollection(data.objc);
var objd = new ModelDCollection(data.objd);
```

all get fetched but with many warning (firefox, chrome) looks like this :

**Warning :**

```
Relation=%o; no model, key or relatedModel (%o, %o, %o) ....
```

1. What is the meaning of this Warning?
2. That's the right to represent this Class Relation with Backbone-relational isn't?

if not?

How can i represent this as a Backbone ModelRelational?

Comment: Hi Mr Smith! i edited my Post and add some Data! Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

In Model A you are defining

`key: 'modelb'`

which links to Model B. However, key should be "a string. References an attribute name on relatedModel" (based on the docs). And I cannot see and model field called modelb

Comment: Is that a question or and answer?

Comment: If you have provided your full model code in the question, then this is the answer: you do need a a field with name "modelb" if you want the refer to it with key. If modelb does not exist, how should the look up work? Maybe key should simply be 'id'.

Comment: can you edit your post with a visual response(example)? Thank you!