# Backbone.RelationalModel using requireJs

Tags: backbone.js, requirejs, backbone-relational

I would like to use [`RelationalModel`](https://github.com/PaulUithol/Backbone-relational) using [`requireJs`](http://requirejs.org/).

Here my code(*)

When I run my module, I get the following warning message:

```
Relation=d; 
no model, key or relatedModel (function (){a.apply(this,arguments)}, 
"tasks", 
undefined).
```

My questions are:

1) what does the warning message means?
2) `relatedModel` and `collectionType` are well defined in my `relations` or should I export the `model` and the `collection` in `define` call?

---

(*)

```
define([
    'backbone',
    'relationalModel'
], function (Backbone) {
    "use strict";

    var User = Backbone.RelationalModel.extend({

        relations: [{
            type: Backbone.HasMany,
            key: 'tasks',
            relatedModel: 'Task',
            collectionType: 'TaskCollection',
            reverseRelation: {
                key: 'hasUser',
                includeInJSON: 'id'
                // 'relatedModel' is automatically set to 'User'; the 'relationType' to 'HasOne'.
            }
        }]

    });

    return User;
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Look at this question: [Creating nested models with backboneJS + backbone-relational + requireJS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9962695/creating-nested-models-with-backbonejs-backbone-relational-requirejs)

By the way, `exports.ModuleModel = ModuleModel;` doesn't work for me. Instead, I use `window.ModuleModel = ModuleModel`. Yes, it's a bit ugly, but it works.

Comment: +1 Thanks for your time, but `window.ModuleModel` should not be used.