# Backbone-relational-Model.subModelTypes with RequireJS modules

Tags: backbone-relational

I'm trying to resolve circular dependency caused by the way to use (1) Backbone-relational Model's `subModelTypes` property and (2) RequireJS modules. I have defined super_model and sub_models in different files as *require* modules. I spent some time to resolve the dependency and come up with a solution. Meanwhile, I found exactly same question/use case and similar solution posted. Here is link:

[Backbone-relational submodels with RequireJS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13276388/backbone-relational-submodels-with-requirejs)

But the solution is negatively voted. So I've got confused, is this the way it should be implemented? Or there is a better way to do it?