# Status of RequireJS and Backbone-Relational and/or Alternative to Backbone-Relational?

Tags: requirejs, backbone-relational

Preface-
I recently learned about Backbone-Relational because I was interested in finding some sort of framework for working with nested backbone models.

Problem-
Console Warning:

```
Relation = r : missing model, key or relatedModel (function (){return i.apply(this,arguments)}, "models", undefined).
```

Comments-
I've done some research and apparently it's a scope issue and there are ways of resolving the warning but as far as I'm aware nothing official.

Question-
Is there any official in depth documentation for dealing with requirejs compatibility?

-OR-

Is there a requireJS savvy alternative?

Comment: Re: your research, are you referring to this?: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9962695/creating-nested-models-with-backbonejs-backbone-relational-requirejs

Comment: Yes, among others. Thank you. The warning can be resolved. It's the information I'm after. The backbonerelational.org documentation isn't very extensive. For instance, I don't understand the context of addModelScope()- like where/when/how it should be used. The documentation just says what it is that it does. It's probably a long shot but I thought I'd put it out there to the community and see what i got back.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a lightweight alternative to Backbone-relational here called backbone associate

https://github.com/rjz/backbone.associate

Also on their page they list for more control

https://github.com/pathable/supermodel

I'm not sure how they will play with r.js but it's definitely worth a shot, backbone.associate looks promising for you!

Comment: Another alternative is [Backbone JJRelational](https://github.com/jj-studio/Backbone-JJRelational), also supporting many-to-many relations.

DISCLAIMER: I am one of the authors. Nevertheless worth a shot ;)